# Trouble getting reservations count

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Basicaly i have a Reservations model and a Product model. I'm trying to count the reservations made at Date.today however the problem is that if i do this:

```
def self.new_reservations_count
   where("canceled = ? and starts_at = ?", false, Date.today).count
end
```

Returns 0 because the starts_at is not there but rather the starts_at of the product which im trying to get but whenever i do that i get a sql error.

Whenever you make a reservation through product i use collection_select to fetch the product info and call it in reservations view with reservation.product.starts_at, name etc...

```
<%= f.collection_select :product_id, Product.where("starts_at > ?", Time.now), :id, :starts_at, { include_blank: "Select a time"}, class: 'form-control' %>
```

I want to be able to assign product.starts_at to reservation.starts_at so that i could be able to call the above function.

Is there any way of doing this?

Comment: http://apidock.com/rails/Module/delegate should be relevant

Comment: use joins. `joins(:product).where(canceled: false, products: { starts_at: Date.today }).count`

Comment: is the `starts_at` field a datetime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When querying for dates what often works is using `BETWEEN` or by converting both the field and the query value to `DATE`

Using `between`:

```
Product.where(starts_at: Time.now.beginning_of_day..Time.now.end_of_day)
```

This will find all `Product`s whose `start_at` is a `datetime` between the `datetime`s of `beginning_of_day` and `end_of_day`.

Passing a `Range` to ActiveRecord will make it use the SQL `BETWEEN` operator:

```
SELECT "products".* FROM "products" WHERE ("products"."starts_at" BETWEEN '2014-07-24 00:00:00.000000' AND '2014-07-24 23:59:59.999999')
```

Converting to `DATE`:

```
Product.where("DATE(starts_at) = ?", Date.today)
```

Since `Date.today` does not contain time information it will look like `2014-07-24` so we have to convert the `datetime` field `starts_at` to a date as well otherwise it won't exactly match:

```
SELECT "products".* FROM "products" WHERE (DATE(starts_at) = '2014-07-24')
```

To fix your method you'll need to join the products table with the reservations table and be table specific when referencing the `starts_at` column:

```
class Reservation < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products

  def self.new_reservations_count
    joins(:products).where("canceled = ? and products.starts_at = ?", false, Date.today).count
  end
end
```

Comment: Already figured it out but thanks :). The joins thing from @jvnill pointed me in the right direction.